# How to make a table refresh in an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, interface, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have developed an `Eclipse` plugin, when I clicked the button a table appears on the view. However, this table does not refresh itself, when I click it again or when I a run operations on the table (such as deletion).

While I was implementing my table, I used `TableColumn` to create my columns and "TableItem" for the rows and values. Therefore, the "TableViewer"s refresh or remove functions does not work.

My table is able to appear, when I click the button and I call this function in the `handler`, such as;

```
HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().showView("ViewID");
```

However, still I am not able refresh it. Any help would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to call `viewer.update()` whenever you want to refresh or update the table. SWT tables and JFace viewers does *not* have a way to monitor the data model.

Alternatively, you can use Eclipse Data Binding to bind the model and the controls/viewers together. Have a look at  [this entry level tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDataBinding/article.html) to get you started.